# What does this code mean: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true,true,true)

Tags: php, phpexcel

can someone explain what this code does...

```
 $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true,true,true);
```

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null, true,true,true);  which portion  in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `$objPHPExcel` is variable pointing to an object which should have been instantiated somewhere
- `getActiveSheet()` is a public method of that object that gets a return value (possibly of object type)
- `toArray(null, true, true, true)` converts the return value (object) to an array and is a method of the returned object itself
- `->` is a notation for accessing properties and methods of an object

This code line means - *Give me the active excel sheet and convert it to an array.*

If you want to dive into the code look for the PHP class of the object it should have comments on its methods.

Answer (score 4):

The code excerpt you posted looks to be from a PHP library called [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet) or, judging by the variable name, an earlier deprecated incarnation of this library called [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

Without seeing the context of the code excerpt, it's difficult to say what `$objPHPExcel` represents. However, it is likely an object instance of the [`PHPExcel`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php) class (or possibly the [`PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/develop/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Spreadsheet.php) class).

Either way, `$objPHPExcel` is most likely an object representing an Excel workbook.

The `getActiveSheet` method ([PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/06-Worksheets.md) / [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/worksheets/)) method allows you to access the currently active worksheet of that workbook i.e. the worksheet that will be active when the workbook is opened in Excel.

The `toArray` method ([PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/07-Accessing-Cells.md) / [PhpSpreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/accessing-cells/)) returns cell values for the whole worksheet in the form of a two-dimensional array of rows and columns. The four parameters passed into this function are as follows...

1. Value returned in the array entry if a cell doesn't exist / empty cell is encountered.
2. Should formulas be calculated for each cell?
3. Should formatting be applied to cell values?
4. Should the array be indexed by actual row and column IDs (true) or by numbers counting from zero.